# Settings keeps showing notifications

Tags: notifications

Everytime I click my settings on my home screen it keeps showing this:

> On-body detection
>
> Keep your device unlocked while it's on you
>
> ---
>
> M
>
> Add another email account Set up your personal or work email

How do I turn this off. I have tried everything.

Comment: Looks like common notifications from a device has just been set up recently? Could you mention the device model and Android version?